# RAM information not making sense using psutil

Tags: python, psutil

How can I be using 89% RAM when I am using 2.11 GB and only have 1.81 GB of available RAM? I currently have 16 Gb RAM installed. How do I fix this? Is there something wrong with my code?

[image: Console Output]

Comment: ______OS?______

Comment: Macos Big Sur: apple M1

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with your code. Since I don't have MacOS, I can only cite the [psutil documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#memory): _**used**: memory used, calculated differently depending on the platform and designed for informational purposes only. **total - free** does not necessarily match **used**. … The sum of **used** and **available** does not necessarily equal **total**._

Comment: @Friknoob Do you run your script as sudo/root? Sometimes applications (like **htop**) need root to display things that normally are not visible. Also remember that nothing is 100% guaranteed to work.